# How to create a table and store data from df to send mails?

Tags: python, html

I need to add my sql table data to email body and send it to required parties. So I have used following method.

```
db_connection = sql.connect(host='', database='term_data', user='root', password='',charset='utf8')
cursor = db_connection.cursor()
raw_data_query =  "select * from terminationdata where Name = 'X1' order by Date desc limit 7"
df = pd.read_sql(raw_data_query, db_connection)
```

Then I add all the output to a variable as below.

```
row_Name=[]
row_Date=[]
row_calls=[]
row_ans=[]
row_min=[]
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row['Date'], row['Calls'], row['Answered_Calls'], row['Total_Minutes'])
    row_Date.append(row['Date'])
    row_calls.append(row['Calls'])
    row_ans.append(row['Answered_Calls'])
    row_min.append(row['Total_Minutes'])
```

Since these data type is a list I converted them in to a str values.

```
row_Date_str = '\n'.join(row_Date)
row_calls_str = '\n'.join(map(str, row_calls))
row_ans_str = '\n'.join(map(str, row_ans))
row_min_str = '\n'.join(map(str, row_min))
```

Finally I made the email body as a table and combineed it.

```
<table>
        <tr>
            
            <td><b>Date</b></td>
            <td><b>Calls</b></td>
            <td><b>Answered_Calls</b></td>
            <td><b>Total_Minutes</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            
            <td>"""+row_Date_str+"""</td>
            <td>"""+row_calls_str+"""</td>
            <td>"""+row_ans_str+"""</td>
            <td>"""+row_min_str+"""</td>
        </tr>
    </table><br/><br/>
```

It works fine, But the issue is I am not getting new rows for each set.All the data are in a same cell as below.

[image]

Can someone show me where I have messed up?

This is how I have used to send emails.

```
import smtplib

sender = 'st@xyz.com'
receivers = ['s@xyz.com']

message = """From: ST <st@xyz.com>
To: SS <s@xyz.com> ; 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: """+mailsubject+"""

Dear All,<br/><br/> Please refer below termination data  :<br/><br/>

D1: <br/>
<table>
        <tr>
            
            <td><b>Date</b></td>
            <td><b>Calls</b></td>
            <td><b>Answered_Calls</b></td>
            <td><b>Total_Minutes</b></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            
            <td>"""+row_Date_str+"""</td>
            <td>"""+row_calls_str+"""</td>
            <td>"""+row_ans_str+"""</td>
            <td>"""+row_min_str+"""</td>
        </tr>
    </table><br/><br/>
    

    




<b>This is an automated email, Please do not reply ...</b>
"""

try:
   smtpObj = smtplib.SMTP('Xc.outlook.com',25)
   smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, message)         
   print ("Successfully sent email")
except smtplib.SMTPException:
   print ("Error: unable to send email")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create new `<tr>` with `<td>`s in them for this to work as you want it to, your issue isn't the Python code but the way you are using HTML.

You see spaces between the values because HTML renders `"\n"` as simply a space, in fact any whitespace is reduced to a single space.

Also `<tr>` stands for Table Row, and if you want to have multiple rows displaying the data, you need to create a new `<tr>` element for each row in your table.

Here's how I would do it:

```
def table_row(date, calls, ans, min):
    return f"""
        <tr>
        <td>{date}</td>
        <td>{calls}</td>
        <td>{ans}</td>
        <td>{min}</td>
        </tr>
    """


table_rows = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    table_rows.append(
        table_row(
            date=row['Date'],
            calls=row['Calls'],
            ans=row['Answered_Calls'],
            date=row['Total_Minutes'],
        )
    )

table_rows_str = "\n".join(table_rows)

message = f"""
<table>
        <tr>
            
            <td><b>Date</b></td>
            <td><b>Calls</b></td>
            <td><b>Answered_Calls</b></td>
            <td><b>Total_Minutes</b></td>
        </tr>
        {table_rows_str}
    </table><br/><br/>
"""
```

Notice I'm also not iterating through the dataframe unnecessarily: you can create the table rows as you are iterating over the data itself.

Comment: Can you help me to figure out how should I edit my email body?I am little bit confused. I have edited my question.

Comment: @veganbuchat you would just need to edit the string in the message variable in my code to reflect the changes.

Comment: Did you mean about the changing the message variable in email body with provided answer?

Comment: I meant this part has to be added to message ```From: ST <st@xyz.com>
To: SS <s@xyz.com> ; 
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html
Subject: """+mailsubject+"""

Dear All,<br/><br/> Please refer below termination data  :<br/><br/>

D1: <br/>```

other than that code should be good to go. hope this answers your question. if not try formulating what your question is differently with an example in code or post a new question